# Spare apostrophe sign in SQL query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to search for a book in the database so I first check if the data informed by the user (can be the title, ISBN or author's name) exists in the DB then I check if part of the data exists and, finally I return all the results.

To do so I wrote this code in Python using SQLAlchemy and FLASK where

- `searchBy` is the name of the column in the DB and
- `searchFor` is the data the user input

.

```
books = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM books JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id \
                   WHERE ({searchBy} = :searchFor) OR ({searchBy} LIKE :searchFor%)", 
                   {"searchFor": searchFor}).fetchall()
```

However, when `:searchFor` is replaced by its corresponding value, it is outputed between aphostropes.

```
 ...(title = 'Animal Farm') OR (title LIKE 'Animal Farm'%)
```

causing this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...              WHERE (title = 'Love') OR (title LIKE 'Love'%)
                                                                      ^
```

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening and how to correctly do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that is happening is because it is passing the variable as a string (as it should in this instance).  Knowing this, you'll want to concatenate the % symbol with the search string.  Something like this should work:

```
books = db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM books JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id \
                   WHERE ({searchBy} = :searchFor) OR ({searchBy} LIKE (:searchFor || '%'))", 
                   {"searchFor": searchFor}).fetchall()
```

Comment: It worked well. I didn't know how to concatenate the strings. Thanks @BShaps.